# Unity - Collider2D not considered in collision check anymore after disabling and enabling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I've got a player, and a shield around him. When a shield is present, it blocks gun projectiles. My CollisionEnter code is

```
if ((col.collider.gameObject.tag == "hurt")  && (col.collider.IsTouching(shield) == false))
{hurt();}
```

It's perfectly fine, if I start the level with the shield already enabled from default. It blocks damage, projectile dissapears. BUT if I have it disabled from beginning and then enable it, it's... hurting me anyway. Even though the "shield" is still tagged to the Collider2D, and that Collider is enabled. I have no idea what to do. Thanks for help!

Here's an image of my player properties:
[image]

And here's a GIF of the improper behaviour after disabling/enabling the shield:
[image]

Here's a full code of the collision check.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{   
    if ((col.collider.gameObject.tag == "hurt_insta") && (col.collider.IsTouching(shield) == false))

    {



        Instantiate(prefab,transform.position,transform.rotation);
        transform.position = new Vector3 (300, 300, transform.position.z);
        Vector2 tempxy = new Vector2 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
        GameObject.Find ("Main Camera").GetComponent<CameraFollow> ().target = null;
        PlayerSolid.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled = false;
        StartCoroutine (Death_prodleva4bit ());


    }


    if ((col.collider.gameObject.tag == "hurt")  && (col.collider.IsTouching(shield) == false))
    { 


        Instantiate(prefab,transform.position,transform.rotation);

        //if (PlayerSolid.transform.localScale.y > 0f) { 
        //  PlayerSolid.transform.localScale -= new Vector3 (0f, 0.36f);
        //} 

        //if (actual_bit == player_bits [8]  ) {
        if (n > 6) {
            transform.position = new Vector3 (300, 300, transform.position.z);
            Vector2 tempxy = new Vector2 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
            GameObject.Find ("Main Camera").GetComponent<CameraFollow> ().target = null;
            PlayerSolid.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled = false;



            StartCoroutine (Death_prodleva4bit ());
        } 

 else {
            hit = true;
            HURT (2);

            //if (n < 7) {
        //      HURT(3);
        //}


        }
```

But it's definitely working as it is - when it's enabled from the start it has no problem. It only occurs if it's not woken up immediately when starting the level.

Comment: Can you provide an image of your player's properties, and maybe a fuller example of where this code is being called? That would provide some clues to what the problem could be.

Comment: https://puu.sh/rje0M/90a5b4ea63.png 
Here's the player (pink), the shield, and player's properties. There's "shield" public Collider2D in the Player_collisions which is assigned to the shield Polygon collider.

The collision code is in the Player_collisions_4bit too, it's in void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col), and it's called everytime a projectile with HURT tag touches me, and it happens to NOT be a shield. and the shield is a child in Player because of a few collision reasons.

Comment: I thought of a quick addition - a gif : https://puu.sh/rjezQ/4d34afd244.gif

Comment: How do you enable/disable it? What code ? Also When do you enable disable it?

Comment: I basically disable/enable it just as it is in the gif. In-game, I let a trigger do it for me. But it does the same thing.

Comment: Don't forget that you can edit your questions - important things like the images you included should be in the main body (I've edited them in for you this time). Can you also share the relevant code where `shield` is used? Seeing a larger snippet for context would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Gonna keep that in mind.

Comment: Oh wow, what. I really hope it is fixed, and it seems like it. I tried adding rigidbody into the main shield body and... for now it seems to work! I'll run it through a few playthroughs!

Comment: Hmmm, interesting! If you can sort out what going on, it may be worth including it in an answer below. (If not, that's fine too - not all problems are easily understandable, even if you know how to work past them.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it a few more times and it really seems to be fixed - So, for some reason, the object that I was asking about in IsTouching needed a RIGIDBODY. I still don't understand it, because if I start the game with the shield on, it works flawlessly! Nonetheless, this fixed it!

Thanks everyone!